matrix combination with unique elements across rows, diagonals, and columns
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$
Now This is a $4 \times 4$ matrix with $16$ elements $4$ unique elements across row , diagonals and columns with elements $\{1,2,3,4\}$
Now, If I want to make a $5 \times 5$ matrix with $25$ elements $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$  elements $\{1,2,3,4\})$ and $5$ elements $\{5\}$, how can I make a new $5 \times 5$ matrix in which elements across row, diagonals and columns are unique.
$\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
5\\
5\\
5\\
5
\end{bmatrix}$
$5 \times 5$
$\begin{bmatrix}
x & x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x & x 
\end{bmatrix}$
Can a matrix property help this, or do I have to brute force for a valid solution?

You need the numbers $1,2,3,4$ once more and $5$ fives to make the desired new Latin square , not $9$ fives.

sorry , my bad
so if we have 1,2,3,4 once more and 5 fives
how can we make one?

@IllDimension101 $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \ 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 \ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \ 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \ 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

It is not clear however what parts of the original matrix (here $4\times 4$) should keep the same. If you just want to construct a Latin square , you need not start with a smaller one.

No the elements shall be {1,2,3,4} and {5 } as an extra element

What do you mean by "an extra element"? Is the square in the comment from user @EnEm OK?

yeah its valid
so for 5x5
elements shall be from {1...... to n}

For a general $n \times n$ matrix, a particular construction as described below will be able to satisfy all three of the above conditions (unique elements along the rows, columns and diagonals). Do note that this is not the only type of  construction possible, and there might be many more.
Also I am also using the numbers $\{0, 1, \dots n-1\}$ instead of $\{1, 2, \dots n\}$ as it's easier to handle with mod operations. You can add $1$ to all elements in the final construction to get the answer to your problem.
Construction
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & \dots & n-1\\
t \bmod n & (1+t) \bmod n & (2+t) \bmod n & \dots & (n-1+t) \bmod n \\
2t \bmod n & (1+2t) \bmod n & (2+2t) \bmod n & \dots & (n-1+2t) \bmod n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(n-1)t \bmod n & (1 + (n-1)t) \bmod n & (2 + (n-1)t) \bmod n & \dots & (n-1 + (n-1)t) \bmod n
\end{bmatrix}$$
For some $t \in \{0, 1, \dots n-1\}$, which we will try to compute now:

Here its trivial to show that each row will have unique elements, regardless of our choice of $t$, due to the fact that $c+x \not\equiv c+y \pmod{n}$ if $x \not\equiv y \pmod{n}$.
If any $j^{\text{th}}$ column has duplicate entries on rows $i_1$ and $i_2$, then that means $j+i_1t \equiv j+i_2t \pmod{n}$ $\implies$ $i_1t \equiv i_2t \pmod{n}$ for some $i_1 \not\equiv i_2 \pmod{n}$. This can not happen when $t$ and $n$ are coprime. So if we take a $t$ which is co-prime to $n$, each column will have unique elements.
If there are some duplicate entries on diagonal $1$ ($i=j$) on rows $i_1$ and $i_2$, then that means $i_1+i_1t \equiv i_2+i_2t \pmod{n}$ $\implies$ $i_1(t+1) \equiv i_2(t+1) \pmod{n}$ for some $i_1 \not\equiv i_2 \pmod{n}$. This can not happen when $t+1$ and $n$ are coprime. So if we take a $t$ where $t+1$ is co-prime to $n$, diagonal $1$ will have unique elements.
If there are some duplicate entries on diagonal $2$ ($i+j = n-1$) on rows $i_1$ and $i_2$, then that means $n-1-i_1+i_1t \equiv n-1-i_2+i_2t \pmod{n}$ $\implies$ $i_1(t-1) \equiv i_2(t-1) \pmod{n}$ for some $i_1 \not\equiv i_2 \pmod{n}$. This can not happen when $t-1$ and $n$ are coprime. So if we take a $t$ where $t-1$ is co-prime to $n$, diagonal $2$ will have unique elements.

So we need to take a $t \in \{0, 1, \dots n-1\}$ such that all three $t-1, t ,t+1$ are coprime to $n$. This can not happen if $2 \mid n$ or $3 \mid n$, but for all other cases ($n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{6}$), we can use $t=2$ to get a valid matrix.
I am sure we can do some auxillary work (like dividing the matrix into $4$ or $9$ submatrices) to get some constructions for the other cases as well, using the same technique as above, but I am leaving that for now. Do let me know if required.

for 5x5 t,t+1,t-1 shallnot bemultiple of 5
5%t != 0
5%1 = 0
5%2!=0
5%3!=0
5%4 != 0 but t+1 = 5 which is multiple of 5 so
n = 5 and t = 2,3
matrix[i][j] = (i + j·t) mod n
so choosing t = 2
ROw 1 will be j++ from j = 0 to 5
0 mod 5 = 0
2 mod 5 = 2
4 mod 5 = 4
6 mod 5 = 1
8 mod 5 = 3
Row 2
1 mod 5 = 1
3 mod 5 = 3
5 mod 5 = 0
7 mod 5 = 2
9 mod 5 = 4
similarly
done row 3 [2,4,1,3,0] row 4[3,0,2,4,1]row5[4,1,3,0,2]
adding1accross,hence
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 4 \
2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5 \
3 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 1 \
4 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 2 \
5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}

Thank you sir , it helped me a lot

but what should be value of t , if i want to make 6x6 matrix?

does that mean n can be only prime number for t to be satisfied?

These are called "Latin squares", if you do a search for that term you'll probably find more than you need to know (although yours have that extra condition about the diagonals). They exist for all $n\ge4$.

Ervin Gergely, A simple method for constructing doubly diagonalized Latin squares, Journal Of Combinatorial Theory (A) 16, 266-272 (1974), available at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316574900533 does what you want: it gives a construction that works for all $n\ge4$.
Here is the example they give for $6\times6$:
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&6\cr5&3&6&1&4&2\cr4&1&5&2&6&3\cr2&4&1&6&3&5\cr6&5&4&3&2&1\cr3&6&2&5&1&4\cr}
$$

Thank you sir , but i find it very hard to understand and comprehend , Transversals and other which i dont understand , but I will try

A transversal in a square matrix is just a set of places in the matrix with exactly one place in each row and in each column. The diagonals are examples.

Making any progress?
